# singular noun-verb agreement with superlative adjective

Tags: verbs, superlative-degree, agreement

Is the noun-verb following sentence correct?:
"Most metaphysics has been determined by it."

I thought that with the superlative adjective 'most', the subject is made plural; but can it also be considered a collective noun thereby making the subject singular? I've tried the sentence with both verbs in three different grammar checkers and they all recognize both verb tenses as correct.

Thank you,
Jodi

Comment: Most sugar is delivered to grocery stores by reputable trucking companies.

Comment: Part of the problem is that *metaphysics* sounds plural, even though it isn't. You can try replacing *metaphysics* with *English*. Once you get a sentence that sounds right with *English*, switch it back to *metaphysics* again. Or you can say *most of the study of metaphysics . . .* or *most of the science of metaphysics . . .*

Comment: The final _s_ on metaphysics is not a plural marker, like that in _cars_. It's a singular-only noun, i.e. it takes a singular verb.

Comment: Physics is a scientific subject. Most physics is taught scientifically.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My question wasn't whether metaphysics is singular or plural; I know that it is singular. My question was whether the superlative adjective 'most' changed it to plural. As Ricky's example illustrates very simply, it does not make it plural.